# Making use of service references in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I've been trying to make use of this [API](http://energywatch.natgrid.co.uk/EDP-PublicUI/PublicPI/InstantaneousFlowWebService.asmx) in order to create a small app that will be run at a set interval in order to monitor a value. I've been told to do it in vb.net using service references and have so far managed to make use of the method that returns the last publication time, but when I try to retrieve the actual information from the table I receive an error:

> "Exception: Compression is Not Enabled,This Web Service expects
>   clients to support GZIP,Deflate Compression"

So far i've been finding it difficult to find any info that is applicable to my current setup so i'm not sure how to progress. Is there anything i'm missing or any resources that would help me get my head around this?

Here is the current code i'm using to get the values.

```
Private Sub Soap(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim svc As New FlowInfo.InstantaneousFlowWebServiceSoapClient()
    Dim str As String = svc.GetLatestPublicationTime().ToString
    MessageBox.Show(str)
    Dim body As FlowInfo.EDPReportBE = svc.GetInstantaneousFlowData()
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess the obvious thing to ask is if your application is using 'gzip' to decompress the data it's being given? http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/

Comment: I don't think it is. I've never used web services before so I wasn't sure if compression was an inbuilt thing in vb.net or something external.

I dug around the documentation a bit more and I think i've pinpointed my issue:
"Thus API’s client should include “Accept-Encoding: zip” header as part of request"

I don't think I have done this in my project yet so I think that's why it isn't returning anything. To my knowledge the request is generated behind the scenes so i'm not sure how i'd go about adding things to the header.